# Configure a docker-registry to use multiple certificates using config.yml

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-registry

I'm setting up a private docker registry on centOS using "docker-distribution". Therefore, I use the "config.yml" to configure the registry. This file looks as follows:

```html
version: 0.1
log:
  fields:
    service: registry
storage:
    cache:
        layerinfo: inmemory
    filesystem:
        rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
http:
    addr: 0.0.0.0:443
    tls:
        certificate: /certs/certificate.crt
        key: /certs/key.key
auth:
    htpasswd:
        realm: somerealm
        path: /auth/registry.password
```

Everything works well so far, but I would like to use two different certificates, one for local traffic and one for remote traffic over the internet. The problem is that I don't know how to specify multiple certificate/key-files in the config. I already tried using a wildcard like "/certs/*.crt" or to add another entry "certificate: /certs/certificate_2.crt"...but it did not work.

I could not find any documentation nor post about this. Does anyone have an idea how I could achieve this?